# How to prevent merging equal prototypes in kproto function from clustMixType package in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am implementing k-prototype clustering using `kproto()` function from `clustMixType` package on the [hepatitis dataset](https://github.com/myildir3/Datasets/blob/master/hepatitis.data.imputed.xlsx). After getting clustering labels, I am matching cluster labels with the class labels using `labelMatcher()` function from the `Thresher` package (Label matching is needed for computing accuracy, sensitivity, precision, F1 score on a dataset with more than two classes). However, since `kproto()` function merges equal prototypes during the clustering, `labelMatcher()` cannot match the class labels with the cluster labels due to having fewer unique cluster labels. I wonder if I can prevent merging the equal prototypes in `kproto()` function. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a solution to prevent merging equal prototypes in `kproto()` function. However, I checked the number of unique clusters after running `kproto()` function. If the desired number of clusters is not equal to the number of unique clusters, I forced rerunning the code using `while` loop.